# WSO2 vault-lookup Xpath expression returns Empty/Blank

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

when I do a simple expression like `wso2:vault-lookup('my-token')` it returns empty. But i have the *my-token* present in the vault.

Has anyone encountered this problem before ? Any possible workaround that you can suggest.

EI version `6.2.0`

Comment: Is this a clustered environment? Did you check from the management console if the "my-token" is available in the secure vault

Comment: no it is not clustered, and yes `my-token` is available in the secure vault, also in the registry level secure vault.

Comment: Can you try to add a new entry in the secure vault and check if it the same behavior for the new entry as well?

Comment: @ShanakaPremarathna yes I have tried that, but it still the same. I can get the encrypted key, but when I'm doing the `vault-lookup` it does not return anything.

Comment: I have tested a similar flowwith a EI 6.2.0 version and observe that this is working without any issues. I have used a log mediator to print the password value and it was printing as expected. 
<log level="custom">
            <property expression="wso2:vault-lookup('my-token')" name="token"/>
         </log>

Comment: Could you confirm that you have run the following command before using the secure vault (./bin/ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure)
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Working+with+Passwords+in+the+ESB+profile

Comment: @ShanakaPremarathna again sorry for the late response, yes i have run all the configurations necessary, also i have tried it on a vanilla version on basic settings, it works. But my suspect is on Keystore. 

`wso2:vault-lookup('my-token')` doesn't return anything, however if i get the encrypted value, i can get it without any issue, but not the decrypted value (`'vault-lookup'`)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following approach?

Run the ciphertool.sh with the following command.

`bin/ciphertool.sh -Dorg.wso2.CipherTransformation=RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA1andMGF1Padding`

Enter the plain text value which you need to encrypt and copy the encrypted value

Navigate to the carbon console and expand the registry browse section.

Go to the following path.

`/_system/config/repository/components/secure-vault`

Above is the location where the registry holds the secure vault properties and the values.

Inside the secure vault, create a new property with a name and paste the encrypted value which you acquired from the initial step.

Try to get the property from the mediation sequence.

`wso2:vault-lookup('prop-name')`

Comment: i'm getting the message of `This option is not define!`, why is that

Answer (score 1):

Since you have confirmed that this is working as expected in the vanilla version of the EI server, can you compare the configurations available in **secret-conf.properties** file located in [EI_HOME]/conf/security directory of the existing server and the vanilla pack (that this working).

Comment: Yeap, i checked, both are identical (except for necessary path changes)

Comment: yes, it's WUM updated, same WUM update on a different node, but in there everything works fine.

Comment: Did you use the default Keystore or is it a different keystore

Comment: different keystore.
EDIT: both environments uses the same configs (apart from necessary changes), only 1 environment doesn't work. Same configs. Hard to pin point where the issue is.